# How to have control over SugarCRM bean id

Tags: web-services, sugarcrm

SugarCRM has by default, inbuilt GUID having a format,
**aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee**
and the field name is "id" also known as Sugar Bean ID.

I am using SOAP Web Service version 4.1

When I supply some value in id field, no entry is created.
I have to supply nothing to id field and then only entry is created with a default bean id format of **aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee**.

How can I make my own custom id as the Bean id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the adding this in the 'name_value_list' array in the call...

```
array('name' => 'new_with_id', 'value' => '1'),
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'new_with_id'? Is it a default field name in SugarCRM or Custom name? Because by default SugarCRM has a field name 'id'.

Comment: It is a default property of the SugarBean that lets SugarCRM know if you are providing the ID that should be used on creation or if SugarCRM should auto create the ID.

Comment: What value exactly do I have to pass in "new_with_id", "1" or is there anything else?